# Problem with Sessions in ASP .NET

Tags: asp.net, session

I have a weird issue with session variables. I'm storing some credentials in sessions variables like this:

```
Session["login"] = "foo";
Session["password"] = "oof";
```

The page is deployed on a certain server. After I logged in on the page, I noticed that other users (who are in the same network area) calling the page were logged in as well! I thought those data would be stored only for me (I suppose the server sends me back some cookies to ensure that) but that's not the case?

I certainly have a lack of knowledge somewhere. What's going on?

Thanks

Comment: Anything that is in *your* session certainly shouldn't be visible to others so I'd look outside of this for a problem. If needs be write simple web pages that store a session value unique to a user (eg IP address assuming you're not goign through a proxy) and another that displays it. This should allow you to prove whether or not session is being shared as you describe. I think its more likely that your code is doing something wrong somewhere else though (eg storing something in application state or on a static variable somewhere).

Comment: Yes I think that too. I'm investigating the issue.Thanks.

Comment: Found it. The origin of this problem was a global variable in the code behind :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend storing a password in a session variable for security purposes. If you must use a session variable, do not store the password in clear text. Use some encryption method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Check your web.config

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9.aspx